# Python 'getopt' syntax, allowing optional command line arguments, longopts not recognized

Tags: python, argv, getopt

```
import sys
import getopt

paper = 0

try:
    argv = sys.argv[1:]
except:
    pass

try:
    options = getopt.getopt(argv, 'p', ["paper"])
except:
    pass

for name in options:
    if name in ['p', '-p', '-paper', '--paper']:
        paper = 1
```

**$ python myApp.py p or -p**

```
-- Works properly
```

**$ python myApp.py -paper or --paper**

```
-- Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myApp.py", line 52, in <module>
for name in options:
NameError: name 'options' is not defined
```

---

Hey gang.  So I am not sure what I am doing wrong that my longopts, "paper" is not being recognized from the command line.

Thank you.

Respectfully,

Slid3r

Comment: You know, if you weren't swallowing all exceptions from `getopt.getopt`, Python would have a handy message for you giving some information on what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try-except` that you have wrapping the two statements is likely masking an error and making it so options isn't assigned. I've rewritten it so those `try-except` statements are gone, as well as fixing some of the usage with `getopt`.

You should probably account for the tuple being returned. Per the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt):

> the first is a list of (option, value) pairs; the second is the list of program arguments left after the option list was stripped (this is a trailing slice of args)

The final product:

```
import sys
import getopt

argv = sys.argv[1:]
options, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'p', ["paper"])

for opt_value in options:
    if opt_value[0] in ['-p', '--paper']:
        print('Paper arg set!')
```

which results in these outputs:

```
~$ python myApp.py --paper
Paper arg set!
~$ python myApp.py -p
Paper arg set!
```

Slice allowing start index past length:

```
> myargs = ['myapp.py', 'a', 'b', 'c']
> myargs[5:]
< []
```

Comment: Thanks!  But ... the [-p --paper] option is not meant to capture any values, it is a boolean.  thus the : and = are improper in the definition and why I left out the 'args' value capture.

Am I wrong to assume that if a user does not enter a command-line argument, 'argv = sys.argv[1:]' would throw an error?

Edit:  Yes I was wrong to assume that.  Removed the error handling.  Still longopts are not recognized.

Comment: I misunderstood then and I'll modify my answer. As far as throwing an error, the slice syntax is forgiving in that it will not throw if you attempt to slice past the end of the iterable, it will just return an empty array.

Comment: I have copy/pasted it EXACTLY as you wrote it above, (thank you again).

I get the same error, it's like it does not like the second char in paper, 'a'.

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/getopt.py", line 211, in short_has_arg
    raise GetoptError(_('option -%s not recognized') % opt, opt)
getopt.GetoptError: option -a not recognized

python myApp.py --paper

Comment: I'm not sure then, here's where I've been running it and testing it out: https://repl.it/join/gdfkzjib-wesh1

See if you can spot any differences between that and your implementation?

Comment: How embarrassing.  Not only can I not find a difference, here is a DIRECT copy/paste of what you wrote.  Still barfs.  I apologize, this is annoying.  https://i.imgur.com/ZYsbhTU.png

Comment: Can you modify the screenshot to include the line above where you're calling it as well?

Comment: Ah, makes sense now! Long args need to be used with `--` and short args need to be used with `-`. It should be ran with either `-p` or `--paper`.

Comment: Yep!  Thanks, buddy.  Scooby Doo Mystery solved.  Although I think next time I will use argparse.  :)